# Upload a file with PUT/POST method on POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, postman

I am trying to upload a file with POSTMAN to this URL

```
http://localhost:3000/bucket/test/files/
```

And should got result in my controller there :

```
    put(request, response, args) {
    //HERE IN THE REQUEST.BODY 
    console.log(request.body)

    let fileManager = request.modules.VMFile;
    let mimeTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/x-icon', '  video/mpeg', 'text/html', 'video/x-msvideo', 'application/msword', 'application/pdf', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/x-rar-compressed'];
    let maxFileSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;

    fileManager.initUpload(mimeTypes, maxFileSize);

    fileManager.receive((files) => {

        fileManager.forEachFileContent(files, (file, content) => {

            minioClient.putObject(request.body.bucket, request.body.name, content, file.size, file.mimetype, function (err, etag) {
                response.setData("File uploaded").apply();
                return console.log(err, etag)
            })

        });
        fileManager.clearFilesFromTmp(files);
    });
}
```

In POSTMAN I got this :

[image: postman]

With nothing on headers but I could only PUT (or POST, I tried to change my route with POST but same issue) the name and bucket field... I got nothing on my files field...

Comment: if this is express application, you need to write `app.put(<URL_HERE>, handler_function)`. your code snippet is incomplete.

Comment: It is a private API based on express, but my snippet is working

Comment: @Cupkek05 Just to clarify, you're getting nothing in your controller when postman fires the request over the network? Also, do you not need content-length and content-type on your headers?

Comment: @DanielLane I dunno because I checked some topic where they advocate to let the content-type empty, Ill try it

Comment: @Cupkek05 It looks like David's suggestion might work for you, give that a try.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

While using `Postman` especially when you test file upload ensure that,

1. in *Headers*:

   - The `Content-type` field has been set as `multipart/form-data` in Headers.
2. in *Body*:

   - `form-data` option should remain as default.
   - Choose `File` option instead of `text` from the dropdown on the right side.
   - Type `File` in the text box where the placeholder is `key`.

Comment: Add content-type with multipart-formdata worked, thanks for your help

Comment: how to send data with content-type: application/json

Comment: @rammanoj Under "Headers" tab (in POSTMAN) you need to add key "Content-Key" (if you start typing you will get auto suggestion) and in the next box you can give "application/json" (again, when you start typing you will get auto-suggestion. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem.
I've lost hours just because I was not doing the last bit `Type File in text box where placeholder is key.` ‍♂️

Comment: Super helpful !! thanks a ton !!

Comment: That's really helpful, wasn't aware we can send file using put also, added step by step guide here:
https://qawithexperts.com/article/web-api/upload-or-send-file-in-postman/438

Answer (score 2):

You might be doing it right but sometimes POSTMAN does not work well.  I wrote an API to accept both text and file.
While invoking service from Postman.

1. I set `Content-Type` as `"application/json"` and `Accept` as `"application/json"`.
2. In body I pass the text and file
   It was not working, I tried multiple times.  I shut down postman and my laptop.

Woke up the next morning hit again and it worked. Below is the image of the working request.

[image]

Comment: Possible to get user.png size while uploading? Any idea on that scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Not all of David's answer worked for me when using `express-fileupload`. In short, I don't require the `Content-Type` header when using `express-fileupload`.

#### Note, these steps are for npm / express-fileupload / Postman

1. Ensure the header `Content-Type` is disabled. Setting this forces `req.files` to be undefined.
2. As per Davids answer, use `form-data` and set the `key` to whatever you require, and upload the file.
3. If you `console.log(req.files.YOUR_KEY)` in your express app, you should have an object with the uploaded file, in my case `req.files.file`.

Here's what postman should look like (once again, disable the `Content-Type` header):

[image: Postman confirugration]

Here's the output within the console when using `console.log(req.files)`:

[image: Debug console]

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was not clear enough, for googlers try the below **extra** steps:

1. Headers:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data
```

2. Body:

   - Add key (file or name of your choice) and change type field for file.
   - Add key (`_method`) with value: `PUT`

**The route sent must be POST.**