# Send image file using PUT method

Tags: file, postman, put

I'm using POSTMAN, and I'm trying to send an file using PUT Method. Is it correct to send it using the x-www-form-urlencoded option?

Also, I can't select the `FILE` field option. How can I do this? I'm trying to edit an user image.

Comment: Hi Hermus, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Consider including an example of the request that are you trying. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: @Hermus fyi the answer is a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282610/8566549)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using Postman especially when you test file upload please ensure that,

in Headers:

```
The Content-type field has been set as multipart/form-data in Headers.
```

in Body:

```
form-data option should be remain as default.
Choose File option instead of text from dropdown at the right side.
Type File in text box where placeholder is key.
```

Hope this helps!

Follow below screen short :

[image]

[image]